# How can we leverage angular change detection to improve performance?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I'm creating my first open source project, a school gradebook. I'm new to angular. 
Question: How can I improve the runtime performance of the gradebook application? The form controls are generated dynamically based on students and assignments. The rendering is taking more time than desired.

I tried to detach the change detector but still taking too much time when change detection is triggered.

When I look into chrome dev tools, this is where the majority of the time is spend doing change detection.

```
  private createFormControls( ) {

    const gradeGroup = this.gradeControls;
    this.clearAllGradeControls(gradeGroup);

      for (let i = 0; i < this.gradebook.students.length; i++) {
        const student = this.gradebook.students[i];
        const studentGrades = this.gradebook.grades.filter( g => g.userId == student.userId);

        for (let j = 0; j < this.gradebook.assignments.length; j++) {
          const assignment = this.gradebook.assignments[j];
          const key = this.createKey(student.userId, assignment.id);
          const grade = studentGrades.find( g => g.assignmentId == assignment.id );
          let fg = new FormGroup({
              grade: new FormControl(grade ?  grade.grade : ''),
              userId: new FormControl(student.userId),
              assignmentId: new FormControl(assignment.id),
           });
            gradeGroup.addControl(key,  fg);
        }      
      }   


  }
```

Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/github/omarolivo/Gradebook

Github: https://github.com/omarolivo/Gradebook

How can I dynamically generate rows and columns of form controls with better performance?

**UPDATE**

After looking into whats causing the main problem in the overall performance, change detection is for the most part slowing down the component. I tried to convert the array of data into RxJS  observable. I'm still struggling with change detection.

Any suggestions on the "correct" pattern/architecture to efficiently use change Detection?

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised to think that ChangeDetection was causing this issue for you, until I realised it wasn't. What you're seeing there is a false positive. The real bottleneck is in the assignment/rendering of the heavy `FormGroup` to the `<form>` element (which just so happens to happen when change detection runs and the value is updated).

I was going to suggest using Angular's [Resolve Guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard) to 'bypass' all of the change detection that occurs when modifying the `FormGroup` but that won't make much of a difference (I tested it and then realised the real problem was elsewhere). I would actually suggest still doing this, not for performance reasons, but architectural ones. I'd move all the logic to a service, and then have the guard inject that service and use it to invoke a resolve call.

The *real* issue is in the number of `FormGroups` your form contains. You're looking at 25 people by 39 columns = **975** `FormGroups`. Each of those `FormGroups` then contain 3 `FormControls`, totalling to almost 3 thousand. That is enormously large and I do not believe that there are any out-of-the-box solutions for this.

What I would suggest doing is to try to minimise the number of visible fields at any given time (as nobody wants to see 975 fields up-front anyway). You could split out your `*ngFor` elements into smaller, divided `*ngFor` elements and then wrap some of them in some `*ngIf` logic so they aren't always rendered (perhaps the `*ngIf` will evaluate to true when the current scroll position is near the top of the element for example).

Another thing you could do is look into more sophisticated lazy loading of `*ngFor` elements. I found an interesting [article](https://medium.com/@vyakymenko/increasing-rendering-performance-in-angular-with-lazy-render-ngfor-ae8c5d16e194) where the writer runs you through creating a 'lazy' `*ngFor` directive. I can't vouch for the quality (or the feasability) of this, but it is definitely worth a try.

As always, `OnPush` change detection is pretty much a **must** and that will help performance a *bit* in this case.

If I think of anything else I'll come back and edit this post.

Good luck!

EDIT:

The Angular CDK has support for  [Virtual Scrolling](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling) built into it. You can create a scrollable container using the `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>` tag and then replacing your `*ngFor` directives with `*cdkVirtualFor`. The rest of the API is the same.

To briefly quote the docs:

> The `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>` displays large lists of elements performantly by only rendering the items that fit on-screen. Loading hundreds of elements can be slow in any browser; virtual scrolling enables a performant way to simulate all items being rendered by making the height of the container element the same as the height of total number of elements to be rendered, and then only rendering the items in view.

Comment: This certainly on the right direction. I started looking into ngx-virtual-scroller. Also, I was aware there are "many" `FormGroups `. Without adding another dependency, is this the best performance we can get out of angular?

Comment: Hi Omar, apologies for the late response. I have added an edit to my answer. I hope it is of help to you.

Comment: Even after removing the creation of all controls on the grid, the performance still bad. thank you so much for your input!